# COM порт, время жизни подключения

Tags: windows, com-порт

Не первый раз сталкиваюсь с проблемой. Стороннее COM устройство делает дисконнект через день/неделю/месяц постоянного опроса. Есть ли какие-нибудь ограничения на количества данных за сеанс или длительность сеанса в подключении WinXP к COM устройству, или это фича самого устройства?

ЗЫ: проверено на 2-х устройствах разного производителя.

ЗЫ2: программирую на c#, SerialPort. Но подозреваю проблема не в этом.

Comment: Где-то завелся счетчик, который переполняется. Или у вас в коде, или в устройстве. В ОС - маловероятно, нашли бы.

Comment: @gbg исключений не происходит, принудительный реконнект (без создания нового SerialPort) пробуждает устройство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ОС ограничений нет, судя по тому что были проверены разные устройства разных производителей, скорее всего где-то вы ошиблись. Посмотрите тут Протокол обмена данными (Контроль четности, Стоп бит) http://www.denvo.ru/pub/hardware/rs-232.html

Comment: Ну я пойму если копилась бы память или отваливался порт после 1-2 часов работы... А то 2 недели отпахал и ушел в дисконнект. Принудительный повторный коннект пробудил устройство. Настройки подключения установлены по ТТХ устройств.

Comment: Пришли к выводу, что забивается стек либо в классе C#, либо стек устройства. Принудительно делаю реконнект с определенной периодичностью